# Difference between npm configuration commands

Tags: npm, npm-init

Are

```
npm config set <key> <value>
```

and

```
npm set <key> <value>
```

synonymous?

Configuration of npm init with both of this commands, add init configuration to /home/.npmrc

```
npm config set init.author.name 'Some One'
npm set init.author.email 'some@one.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are synonymous.

Check NPM's source code on GitHub: The code of the `set` command is short and calls `config`'s `set`.

https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/master/lib/set.js

```
module.exports = set

set.usage = 'npm set <key> <value> (See `npm config`)'

var npm = require('./npm.js')

set.completion = npm.commands.config.completion

function set (args, cb) {
  if (!args.length) return cb(set.usage)
  npm.commands.config(['set'].concat(args), cb)
}
```

`config` command: https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/master/lib/config.js